# How do I vectorize a function in numpy with some fixed parameters?

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have written a code for approximating a function with the Bernstein polynomials ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial )

at

https://github.com/pdenapo/metodos-numericos/blob/master/python/bernstein.py

I have a function that gives the polynomial approximating f as bernstein(f, n, p) (where f is the function that I want to approximate, n is the degree and p the point where it is evaluated.

```
def bernstein(f, n, p):
    return np.sum(
        [f(k / n) * st.binom.pmf(k, n, p) for k in np.arange(0, n + 1)])
```

Now I want to generate a plot of this function where f and n es fixed, and p runs though a vector generated by np.arrange
So I am vectorizing the function in the following way:

```
 bernstein3 = lambda x: bernstein(f, 3, x)
 bernstein3 = np.vectorize(bernstein3)
 y3 = bernstein3(x)
 plt.plot(x, y3, 'green', label='$B_3$')
```

It works. But I guess there must be some more elegant, or perhaps more pythonic way of doing this. Any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: Please post the `bernstein` function within the question, as the answer depends on how it is implemented. Also, I suppose it could be assumed that `f` is a vectorized function in the first place, otherwise it would be difficult to work around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SciPy statistic functions are vectorized, your `bernstein` function can be modified in a straightforward manner to work that way:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

def bernstein(f, n, p):
    # Vector of k values
    k = np.arange(n + 1)
    # Add a broadcasting dimension to p
    pd = np.expand_dims(p, -1)
    # Compute approximation
    return np.sum(f(k / n) * scipy.stats.binom.pmf(k, n, pd), -1)
```

It would be used simply as this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return np.abs(1 / 2 - x)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = f(x)
plt.plot(x, y, 'blue', label='f(x)')
y_approx = bernstein(f, 10, x)
plt.plot(x, y_approx, 'orange', label='f_approx(x)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Many thanks but I don't undersand the line       pd  = np.expand_dims(p, -1) What is supposed to do?

Comment: @PabloDeNapoli It adds an extra dimension at the end of the shape of `p`, so whatever shape it has the computations of the polynomials are broadcasted along that dimension (see [NumPy's broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)). Then `np.sum` reduces that dimension, so the output has the same shape as the input.